# postgresql how to return digits of certain length

Tags: postgresql

Say I have value 5 in a column, I want to return five 99999's. If its 3, then return 999. The number in the column is variable, how do I return variable number of digits of same value length.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Also give some [mre] and show relevant tables and SQL definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `REPEAT()`:

```
SELECT REPEAT('9', col)
FROM tablename
```

Change `col` to the column's name.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e0c1877cba1a8e06e21231ea7e0f2b0).